# Text wrap to columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have unlimited length of text, and a fixed height container with no vertical scrollbar option, basically the text overflow the container, but it is hidden.

The requirement is to wrap this text to same height columns like the parent container,  container has the option to have horizontal scrollbar.

Al this need to work in responsive layout - what means the text parent container  height will be less, and all text columns will be restructured.

E.g. if the current text columns was initial 3 column on smaller devices can go to 4, or 5 column.

I searched Google, but haven't found any possible solution.

Any solution, or guide will be big help - at least to know in which direction to start

- CSS, or JavaScript, jQuery solutions are welcome.

Initial has the height auto -  click button to set the height/ after the height is set need to wrap the text and set in columns to not exced vertical height, instead will be horizontal aligned columns.

```
ADD CODE HERE
```

[jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/farkasimre/zsL8p4wa/1/)

Comment: Can you show an image demonstrating what you are looking for and what you have with you currently?

Comment: can you provide fiddle so it will be better to answer your question

Comment: And yes, responsive design works that way. You have one column in mobile and three column in main window. You can use `col-xs-3` or something and make a lot of `col-xs-3` or `col-md-1`... Something like that?

Comment: i will try to make a fiddle - and share  - maybe will be better to understand

Comment: Hm... not so easy - you need to find the way to compare text length (number of characters?) with container height, and if text length is higher (if overflow is present), make additional columns...

Comment: yes - something - but the char lenght is not the best solution some custom fonts width/ height can vary - i had this once this issue

Comment: Huh, now i seen fiddle -it is not just text,  there are html elements, and i guess - that content/html structure is unknown / will be always dynamic?

Comment: yes - content is dynamic

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using CSS columns but I don't have time to work on this right now. Maybe someone else can try. The only problem is that is doesn't work on IE8 and IE9, though those have low user statistics in the US the last time I checked. Might be a solution if those browsers aren't necessary. [Responsive-Friendly CSS Columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an jquery plugin for - http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/ . This one solve all what i need.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your data in another div inside the opendoc and increase its width.

```
<div class="opendoc"> // width fixed Change Height
      <div class="resizablediv"> // Change the width
          {{Your data}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need to have columns  - this is requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but not really perfect. Such problems always need a lots of try/fail tests…

You need to have two nested elements:

```
<div class="opendoc">
  <div class="opendoc-inside">
    [Content]
  </div>
</div>
```

.opendoc will receive a fixed height.
.opendoc-inside will have columns and fixed width;

depending of your device width, you choose a number of columns, I choos 2 for the exemple;

Now with javascript:

1. set columns 2 and width 100% on .opendoc-inside
2. if height of .opendoc-inside is greater than height of .opendoc:

   - add 1 column and 50% to the width of .opendoc-inside
   - goto 2
3. else your are ok

This solution generate a reflow on each test. this could become very slow.
You need to avoid to launch this operation on each resize event…

Comment: checking - on first look dosn't look  what i need.